# Creating a new thread in a Yesod handler

Tags: multithreading, web-services, haskell, functional-programming, yesod

I was wondering, could somebody give an example how to start threads from inside a Yesod handler?

I want something like this:

1. User goes to mypage.com/create, which is the Yesod route CreateR
2. User POSTS by pushing a button on the page
3. The POST handler for CreateR forks a new thread, then redirects the user to some "success" page.
4. The thread continues to run in the background, altering STM variables which other handlers will access.

I was using liftIO, but it was crashing with the following error:

```
Exit code: ExitFailure 139
```

The documentation says something about resourceForkIO, but I can't get the types to work, since I have no idea where/how to use that function.

Comment: Did you run by this? [ResourceT tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/resourcet)

Comment: Looks interesting, but the problem is I have no idea how it integrates with Yesod. Yesod types aren't exactly easy to navigate. Either way, the link is super helpful!

Comment: if I  understood [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.4/docs/Yesod-Core.html#g:10) correctly, then you should be able to use `runResourceT` or `liftResourceT`. That tutorial should tell you how to make/use the ResourceT monad.

Answer (score 2):

I do it all the time, especially for long running tasks:

```
liftIO $ forkIO $ customizerJob cnStr env
```

I do not use ResourceT or any TVars to exchange information and progress. Rather i use tables in db. Very simple, does not require arcane knowledge of haskell monad transformers and STM :)

Comment: Seems inefficient... nothing I'm storing needs to be in persistent storage. Also, STM is dead easy in Haskell! That's not my difficulty.

Comment: You can use Yesod App type to store whatever TVar you want to use there. Then retrieve it with getYesod, pass it to your forked thread. This btw does not require any ResourceT

Comment: I take it whatever task you are forking is long running. In this case interfacing with db is the least of your worries.

Comment: My difficulty is how to properly fork a thread in Yesod. Once I've got the thread forked, I know what to do with it :P It's not so much that my process is long running, but that it's a "background" process. It's an online game: the background process updates game state, and Yesod serves these updates when it gets requests.

Comment: Perhaps you do not have correct ghc flags in cabal file? I have this: -threaded -O2 -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N

Comment: It is not likely that forking is the problem here. It's just one line:
liftIO $ forkIO $ yourFunction arg1 arg2
I think your function has a bug in it. SO create a simple test case just to test forking itself and work your way from there.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right I'll see if I can get a minimal test case. I might have discovered a Yesod bug.